# Does the 300 hp IO550 conversion require an auxiliary tank on the Cessna 182?

Tags: piston-engine, fuel-tanks, cessna-182

Does the 300 hp conversion with a continental IO 550 always require an auxiliary tank when used on a Cessna 182?  I see some of these conversions indicate an auxiliary tank is present under pilot seat but I would like to try to avoid this.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.avweb.com/news/maint/181623-1.html) gives a slightly dated (2002) overview of the engine upgrade options for a 182. There's no mention of auxiliary tanks being required, but it does note that for at least one option they're typically a good idea:

> The IO-550 engine is a guzzler and if you don't have long-range tanks,
>   you'll need them. Indeed, you'll probably want to consider Flint tip
>   tanks for your Skylane.

It's possible that you've seen conversions where, for whatever reason, a cabin tank was added instead of - or even in addition to - tip tanks.

If you're looking into an upgrade then if you aren't already a member you should consider joining the [Cessna Pilots Association](http://cessna.org/) and search through their forums (members only) for whatever you can find. I found one thread on upgrading the C182 to an IO-550 but it didn't mention the fuel tanks at all, although I didn't search thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The modification is done in accordance with [AIR PLAINS STC SA00152WI](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjv7Lf4xLTJAhXDwI4KHdjTD6sQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fairplains.com%2Findex.php%2Fsupport%2Fdrawings-documents%2Fcategory%2F19-air-plains-cessna-182%3Fdownload%3D58%3A182023-continued-airworhiness&usg=AFQjCNEauqW5eMpPYACK-x6sIcEqv808hA&bvm=bv.108194040,d.c2E&cad=rja), which has no mention of any auxiliary fuel tank in the 'parts installed' section.

Also, the document says,

> Fuel flows by gravity from the wing tanks to a four position selector valve..

There is no mention of auxiliary fuel tank anywhere.